# Is the following repetition unnecessary?

Tags: fiction, creative-writing

> I peered through the glass.
>
> It was a bird. At first I thought it was a crow because of its black
>   feathers; they were so black they shone in the moonlight like a pair
>   of sword blades. However, after looking at it keenly, I realized it
>   wasn't. First, its beak wasn't that big. **The beak of a crow** was thick
>   and long, as if it were an extension of its face. **The beak of this
>   bird**, on the other hand, was almost as small as a needle. Also, unlike
>   **the angry eyes of a crow, this bird's were round and expressionless**.
>   They didn't convey any feeling—just pure, indifference void. The
>   most noticeable feature, though, was a yellow spot on each wing. They
>   looked like the rank badges that officials wear on their shoulders.

As you can see I repeat The X of the crow...and X of the bird twice.

Is the repetition above unnecessary? Should I use another phrasing instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that repetition is unnecsssary.  No, you do not necessarily need to change it.

Parallel construction is a valuable tool and can make your paragraph easier to read, especially if you're including a comparison as in this narrative.

You may want to adjust your other comparisons so that they all have similar structures, but doing so is purely a stylistic choice.

---

On an un-related note, you should standardize your tense.  You switch between past and present too quickly.  ("realize" should be "realized", for instance.)

Comment: Oh, that was a typo. Thanks for noticing.